# Operand should contain 1 column(s) when using 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables; `COMMUNITIES`, `MEMBERS` and `CHECKINS`.

Based on the visitor's community choice, I want the list the last check in of members that belong to that community.

I am receiving `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` error with the following code.

I will appreciate your help!

```
    cFilter = Request.QueryString("Filter")


SQL = "SELECT C.CheckinID, C.CheckInPlatform, C.MemberID, C.VENUENAME, C.VENUECITY, C.VENUECOUNTRY, C.VENUECREATEDAT, C.CheckInDateEntered"
    SQL = SQL & " FROM CHECKINS C"
    SQL = SQL & " WHERE C.CheckinID"
    SQL = SQL & " IN ( SELECT MAX(CheckinID)"
    SQL = SQL & " FROM CHECKINS"
    SQL = SQL & " GROUP BY MemberID"
    SQL = SQL & " )"
    SQL = SQL & " AND C.MemberID"
    SQL = SQL & " IN ( SELECT M.MemberID, M.CommunityID"
    SQL = SQL & " FROM MEMBERS M"
    SQL = SQL & " WHERE M.CommunityID = "& cFilter &""
    SQL = SQL & " )"
    SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY C.CheckInDateEntered DESC"
    Set objCheckins = objConn.Execute(SQL)
```

Comment: It now seems to me that I shouldnt be using IN for community check. But I dont know how to fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following segment:

```
C.MemberID IN ( SELECT M.MemberID, M.CommunityID
    FROM MEMBERS M
    WHERE M.CommunityID = <your var here>
    )
```

should be broken down to:

```
(
(C.MemberID IN ( SELECT M.MemberID
    FROM MEMBERS M
    WHERE M.CommunityID = <your var here>
    )
)
OR
(C.MemberID IN ( SELECT M.CommunityID
    FROM MEMBERS M
    WHERE M.CommunityID = <your var here>
    )
)
)
```

---

Though I think the later segment of `OR` clause can be skipped.

### EDIT

Since you are selecting `M.CommunityID` with the condition `M.CommunityID = <your var here>`; a simple statement like: `C.MemberID = <your var here>` would suffice.

Comment: how is it different than what I have? Its same with what I did.

Comment: @Efe What is your current query?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cfdb/3 but this is without checking the community element